# Virtualized II7 page runs slow when querying against SQL server

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, virtual-machine

OK… I’ve been tasked to figure out why an intranet site is running slow for a small to medium sized company (less than 200 people).  After three days of looking on the web.  I’ve decided to post what I’m looking at.  Here is what I know:

Server:  HP DL380 Gen9 (new)
OS:  MS Server 2012 – running hyper-v 
RAM:  32GB

Server 2012 was built to run at most 2 to 3 VMs at most (only running one VM at the moment)
16GB of RAM dedicated for the VHD (not dynamic memory)
Volume was created to house the VHD
The volume has a fixed 400GB VHD inside it.
Inside that VHD is server 2008r2 running SQL 2008r2 and hosting an iis7 intranet.

Here is what’s happening:
A page in the intranet is set to run a couple of stored procedures that do some checking against data in other tables as well as insert data (some sort of attendance db) after employee data is entered.  The code looks like it creates and drops approximately 5 tables in the process of crunching the data.  The page takes about 1min50secs to run on the newer server.  I was able to get hold of the old server & run a speed test:  14 seconds.

I’m at a loss… a lot of sites say alter the code.  However it was running quick before.

Old server is a 32bit 2003 server running SQL2000… new is obviously 64bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue... just took a while for me to get back to this.  Hopefully this will help others.

Turned on SQL Activity Monitor under tools\options => at startup => Open Object Explorer and Activity Monitor.

Opened Recent Expensive Queries.  Right clicked on the top queries and selected Show Execution Plan.  This showed a missing index for the db.  Added index by clicking the plan info at the top.  Added the index.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should find out where the `slowness` is coming from.

The bottleneck could be in SQL-Server, in IIS, in the code, on the network?

- Find the SQL statements that are executed and run them directly in SQL server.
- Run the code outside of IIS web pages
- Run the code from a different server

Comment: Thx Peter!  I've run the code on the old server & it's pretty quick.  I've found something in another piece that I'm going to try.  Going to turn off the power-saving feature in the new Xeon processors... according to the article I'll gain performance on the queries.